Migrating from Angular version 13 to version 14
I have an existing project that was developed with Angular version 13, now I'm asked to migrate to higher version (version 16).
I read in some Stack Overflow questions and the docs that I should upgrade version by version, so I started from 13 -> 14.
After following the instructions from the docs, I get the following error every time I want to run the project I get the following error:
This version of CLI is only compatible with Angular versions ^13.0.0 || ^13.3.0-rc.0,
but Angular version 14.3.0 was found instead.
Please visit the link below to find instructions on how to update Angular.

https://update.angular.io/

I followed the docs that said that I have to run ng update @angular/core@14 @angular/cli@14, I also installed version 14 of the Angular CLI globally.
Running npm run ng version gives me the following result:
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/
    

Angular CLI: 14.2.10
Node: 18.16.1 (Unsupported)
Package Manager: npm 10.8.2
OS: win32 x64

Angular: 14.3.0
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... language-service, localize, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, platform-server, router

Package                         Version
---------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect       0.1303.11
@angular-devkit/build-angular   13.3.11
@angular-devkit/core            13.3.11
@angular-devkit/schematics      14.2.10
@angular/cdk                    13.3.9
@angular/material               13.3.9
@nguniversal/express-engine     13.1.1
@schematics/angular             14.2.10
rxjs                            7.8.1
typescript                      4.6.3


Can you share the output of npm ng version to know which version you have installed in your project?

Sorry for taking too long,
I've edit the post and provided the result of the command you gave me.

Hmm seems you have a mix of 13 & 14 versions installed in there. have you tried manually installing latest 13.x for @angular-devkit/schematics, @schematics/angular & rest of Angular 14.x packages you have installed (CLI too) first? You can do so by npm i @angular-devkit/schematics@13 @schematics/angular@13... for all pkgs in v14. Then upgrading them all as usual

Nice, this problem has been solved... I am having issues with other stuff like somethings don't exist in the newer version of Angular but that's another topic for another Question
Can you please Post this as an answer so I can market the "Accepted answer"

Awesome, glad it got solved! Gonna post the answer now. I'll update the existing one to include last comment. Thanks :)

Seems you have a mix of 13 and 14 versions installed in there.
Try installing latest 13.x versions for @angular-devkit/schematics, @schematics/angular and rest of Angular 14.x packages you have actually installed (CLI too) first
You can do so by npm i @angular-devkit/schematics@13 @schematics/angular@13 for all packages that you have now installed with version v14.x. Then upgrade them as usual.
In this regard what I usually do is run the project's installed Angular CLI to perform the update to avoid errors like this. Angular CLI is clever enough to use a newer version in order to perform the upload
Run
npm run ng update @angular/cli@14 @angular/core@14

And it will use the project's Angular CLI v13 to perform the update. Which in turn will download a newer one in order to proceed (but it will automatically choose a compatible one)
This way no need to install a global one also :)

I actually try to avoid installing anything globally to avoid issues like this one when switching between projects


It's a nice trick actually, I didn't think about it, though it did not work still the same error

You can use the Official Angular Update Guide in this link:
https://angular.dev/update-guide
Only you need choose the angular version in "from" and "to" select fields and press "Show me how upgrade!" button and the site show how you can upgrade your angular version step by step.
Good luck!

Ye I followed the instructions written in the docs but it didn't workout for me,
Thanks anyway
